# Angular 2 Hover Particular list

Tags: javascript, angular

Good day,

How to apply a method only when a particular li is being hover.

Code Example:

**app.component.ts**

```
changeStyle(event) {
      this.colorMe = event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'imRed' : 'imBlue';
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
    <b [ngClass]="colorMe">
      Color Me
    </b>
  </li>
  <li (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
    <b [ngClass]="colorMe">
      Color Me
    </b>
  </li>
  <li (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
    <b [ngClass]="colorMe">
      Color Me
    </b>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS**

```
.imRed{
  color: red;
}
.imBlue{
  color: blue;
}
```

What happen here is when I hover a particular `<li>` all `<li>` is being color. and I want only to color a specific `<li>` when it is being hovered.

Comment: The problem is that you have a single variable to handle multiple `<li>`... I'd suggest you to use `*ngFor` and pass the `index` to `[ngClass]="colorMe[i]"` or even `[class]="colorMe[i]"`.

Comment: great idea i'll try using that. i just trying to figure out how to use this variable only when `<li>` is hover like the `$(this).hover` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you only have one `colorMe` variable that every `li` is dependent on. But, any solution to this would be over engineering when you could resolve this without any "code". The following below should do the trick (just using CSS).

**app.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="hover">
    <b>
      Color Me
    </b>
  </li>
  <li class="hover">
    <b>
      Color Me
    </b>
  </li>
  <li class="hover">
    <b>
      Color Me
    </b>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS**

```
.hover b {
  color: blue;
}

.hover:hover b {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: yeah i can do that. but im trying to figure out how to reuse this method only when a particular `<li>` is hover. just like a jQuery `$(this).hover...`

Comment: The problem is that you don't have anything unique to identify the individual `<li>`. If you were to add some sort of unique identifier to them you could get the desired result. (like developer033 suggested)

Comment: i ended up creating 3 method and applying to li one by one. `changeStyle1(event) {
  }` `changeStyle2(event) {
  }` `changeStyle3(event) {
  }`